# Spring boot Transactional doesn't rollback

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions

I'm trying to rollback update with `@Transactional` annotation.

But it doesn't working on any exception.

```
public abstract class MyService<T1 extends MyDao<T2>, T2 extends MyMapper> {

  private final T1 myDao;

  public MyService( T1 myDao ) {
    this.myDao = myDao;
  }

  public updateSomething() {
    try {
      myDao.updateSomething();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      ...
    }
  }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class MyDao<T extends MyMapper> {

  private final T myMapper;

  @Transactional( rollbackFor = Exception.class )
  public void updateSomething() throws Exception {
    myMapper.updateSomething();

    throw new Exception();
  }
}
```

When I throw exception in `MyDao.updateSomething()`, rollback not working.

I've tried to move `@Transactional` annotation to `MyService.updateSomething()` and removed `try-catch`, it was same.

I saw the transaction rollback log, but nothing was rollback.

```
[DEBUG ] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager[processRollback:833] - Initiating transaction rollback
[DEBUG ] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager[doRollback:345] - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1241981043 wrapping net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.ConnectionSpy@1347fc2]
[DEBUG ] o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager[doCleanupAfterCompletion:389] - Releasing JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1241981043 wrapping net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.ConnectionSpy@1347fc2] after transaction
```

Why rollback doesn't working?

Comment: Did you enable Transactions?

Comment: Sure, I've used ```@EnableTransactionManagement``` on my DatabaseConfiguration class

Comment: I'm using multiple database connections. I've found that my abstract class doesn't use correct transactionManager.

Comment: Don't do a catch in your service as that will break tx management (assuming your service is the actual `@Transactional`) also make sure you are using the proper tx manager for the technology you are using. THe log show the `DataSourceTransactionManager` but when using JPA this will not work. Also there could be an issue in your dao implementation (especially if you mess around iwth connections yourself instead of  using a pre-pound one). Finally make sure your DB actually supports transactions (MySQL with MyISAM tables doesn't).

Comment: Using transactionManager with abstract class calls only ```@Primary``` transactionManager. That was the problem. After ```@Override``` the method want to apply transaction in child class, and set ```@Transactional( transactionManager = "txManagerName" )``` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

By default Spring rolls transaction back a for `RuntimeException`, so you should use plain `@Transactional` and throw `RuntimeException` if you want to roll back.

Also make sure you don't start another transaction within `myMapper.updateSomething()`.

Comment: But he configured `rollbackFor=Exception.class` to override this default behaviour.

Comment: To me it's pointless to override default behavior in this case. Even if we need a custom exception for some reason it's better to extend it from `RuntimeException` to be sure transaction is rolled back.